# Error occurred attempting to retrieve page templates. Contact administrator and check page builder feature registered correctly the MVC project

Tags: c#, kentico

This is my Application.config File

```
  public class ApplicationConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterFeatures(IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            // Enable required Kentico features

            // Uncomment the following to use the Page builder feature
            //builder.UsePageBuilder();

            //builder.UseScheduler();
            builder.UsePageRouting(new PageRoutingOptions
            {
                //EnableAlternativeUrls = true
            });
        }
```

And am getting this error when am ready to achieve this

[image]

I was trying to add these as page and get this error

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is the **UsePageBuilder** commented out? This has to be enabled in order to use page builder.  I would also recommend checking this [post on Kentico's DevNet](https://devnet.kentico.com/questions/getting-403-error-with-page-builder) and there are also other discussions on this topic on the devnet.kentico.com site.